# What does "nothing means anything" mean?

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain me the meaning of this phrase? I heard it in a song like: "I can show you that nothing means anything". I get the context, but can anyone explain me the meaning?

Comment: [Nothing](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nothing?q=nothing). [Mean](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mean?q=mean). [Anything](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anything?q=anything)

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Please support it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[**mean nothing or not mean anything**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mean)

> to have no importance
>
> *After yesterday, your apologies mean nothing.
> It was just one little kiss and it didn't mean anything.*

So there is nothing that is important to the singer